# Insert image using html

Tags: javascript, java, html, css

I have an image located in here D:\clone4\java-security-service\src\main\resources\images and I want to add it to my html page, but it doesn't seem to work. I tried many ways like:

```
<img style="max-width: 170px;" src="./images/piechart.jpg" alt="pie-chart">
```

but I get nothing. My Html file is located inside a java project. I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Is your HTML page located directly inside of the resources folder, in a folder inside the resources folder, or somewhere else entirely?

Comment: The html file is located in `D:\clone4\java-security-service\ ` ? try using `<img style="max-width: 170px;" src="src/main/resources/images/piechart.jpg" alt="pie-chart"> ` in that case

Comment: my html file is located in D:\clone4\java-security-service\src\main\resources\templates\scheduleraction\html.vm

Comment: What web server do you use? Spring? Java/Jakarta EE?

Comment: Then you need to fix the value of `src`, because `./images/piechart.jpg` means "the piechart.jpg file that exists in a folder called images that is located in the parent folder of the folder where the HTML file where piechart.jpg is being inserted is". And that's just not where the picture is.

Comment: Do you have a directory named `static` or `WEB-INF` inside `src/main/resources`? Where exactly is your HTML file?

Comment: @dan1st no sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Absolute` path, not the `Relative` one. So give the whole path since both locations of *HTML* file and *image* are from different folders.
Give ***`src`*** attribute: `D:\clone4\...\images` But Try using *`forward slashes`* instead of *`backslashes`* <strike>and prepend with `file://`, So the link would be like</strike>

`C:/clone4/.../images/piechart.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

Open the image in your web browser. Then copy the path and add it to attribute `src` of *img* src location looks like this ***`file:///D:/clone4/.../images/piechart.jpg`***

Comment: Tried that but it's not working unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

```
src="./images/piechart.jpg"
```

Try moving the jpg into the same folder where html file located. Then remove the path and put is as just

```
src="piechart.jpg"
```

Answer (score 0):

How about you create a new folder.Lets call the folder Project. This Project folder would include your HTML files, CSS, Javascript and it would also contain your images. So there would be 4 other folders in your Project Folder. Put your various code in their respective folders, same applies with the images.

Then if you want to access the images from the Image folder,

```html
<img src=.../Images/picture.jpg>
```